# Math.SE chatrooms: how far off-topic is acceptable?

Tags: discussion, chat

### Background

Math.SE has an associated [chat functionality](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com). This can be useful for lots of things - there's a [general mathematical chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics) which handles lots of quick little questions; there's a [moderator office chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/20352/math-mods-office) which facilitates informal conversation with the moderators; there are [various](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2318/set-theory) [themed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13473/linear-abstract-algebra) [rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19167/modern-abstract-analysis) focused on specific areas of math; and there's a [general socialization chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/112937/cafe-and-tavern-on-the-math-se).

Chat's moderation is somewhat different than the main site. For one, flags in chat can alert all mods from any site in the network who are currently active in chat (and some non-moderators too). Individual users who set up or maintain rooms can limit participation in those rooms to a select group if they desire using "[gallery mode](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)" unlike the main site where there is no feature that behaves exactly the same way.

There also seem to be less in the way of meta discussions around chat. For instance, the chat tag currently contains [98 questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat) (99 once this is posted).

### Question

How far off-topic can a chatroom go before it is considered too off-topic to be associated with MSE? Let's define on-topic as primarily or secondarily mathematical in nature or related to the functioning of MSE, and off-topic as things that are not on-topic. Some level of general socialization about non-mathematical stuff between MSE members is expected in chat - things like the weather, pictures of pets, interesting puzzle games, etc. have all been fairly successful topics in the general socialization chatroom. But sometimes chatrooms become highly focused on essentially non-mathematical subjects, like geopolitics, sport, or religion. How do we feel about this as a community?

Comment: How would you define "off-topic" in a math.se chatroom?  That's a term you use throughout your post, and without an operational definition of "on-topic", leaves the question, and readers' interpretation of "off-topic" open to subjective interpretations.

Comment: Good point, I've added a line about that. (No need to ask for my reply here on another post in such a short time span.)

Comment: Yes. And it's a crucial point, which, thanks to you, you addressed.  There really has been no "Bible" of "on-topic math.se chatrooms", so your guess is as good as any. But, nonetheless, a guess.  Generally, the operational definition has been:  Accept the chat, unless and until the chatroom is the source of drama and conflict.  When interactions remain civil, there's no need to intervene.  It's when conflict, with flags flying, and such occur, that mods intervene to freeze a chatroom.  That has happened relatively rarely over my eleven years here.  So please explain your sudden curiosity?

Comment: Mind you, @KReiser, chat rooms to not demand your presence; if a chat doesn't suit someone, they need not participate.  As you mention, chat is independent of math.se. So, tell me, are you seeking for math.se to police it's chatrooms, too? Despite the presence of at least four math.se mods?

Comment: You seem to be reading a lot in to the post. At this point I am simply trying to gauge community opinions. From your comments so far, it sounds to me like your answer is that there should be no level of on-topic requirement. If this is what you believe, I'd encourage you to write it as an answer.

Comment: The Internet has been a constant source of "there's no way someone would do X." --> "oh my God someone is doing X - and now they're doing $X^2$!" for me. So while i know there's a preference for keeping discussions away from specific instances, it would certainly help me if I knew of any specific instances that raised this question.

Comment: I agree, @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC.  This entire question seems cloaked in "generality", without any context, example, reference.  Until the OP discloses the motivation for their question, it leaves the specifics to everyone's imagination.

Comment: The conversation in this room is the much needed context that OP missed: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office

Comment: I can understand the OP making a conscious choice to ask the question in terms of general policies - keeping some distance can help keep the discussion calmer and saner. But if (to be dramatic)  someone is running a pro-dog fighting chat room, I think that's worth knowing specifically.

Comment: Again, I agree that's a valid strategy.  I don't understand the example, as I've never encountered anyone running a pro-dog fighting chat room, but I have no doubt that the mechanisms are *already in place* to bring attention to the room, and have it frozen/deleted, if ever it were to show up.

Comment: Is there a way to send a muffin basket + sympathy card to the moderators?

Comment: @Goku Is it by design or accident that [your math chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141751/from-northern-galaxy-7th-universe) is devoted to religion and devoid of math?  It seems to bother  some users that one of the most highly active math chat rooms listed concerns contentious religious discussion.

Comment: By accident, actually. The original reason why I created a room, was because I needed a separate place to talk about stuff such as games, anime and tech, in detail, without disrupting or dominating other chats. I also happen to invite some people over from C.SE, which is how the religion debate started, and usually a debate on religion/politics lasts *really* long @BillDubuque

Comment: I concur with @Bill.  Particularly as a Gallery room, the room is completely under the control of the room owner, who chooses who can participate, and who cannot, and so at any moment, could have prohibited out-of-hand religious comments.  Note the owner's former room was permanently frozen due to volatility erupting within the chatroom.  One of two chatrooms I've known to be forcefully frozen in my eleven years on this site.

Comment: @amWhy - What are the procedures / mechanisms that are already in place for someone to use if they think a specific chat room is operating  outside the proper boundaries for a math.se chat room? I'm really bad at discovering the correct button or contact link in the SE interface, and guess that others might be too.

Comment: If you (and anyone else) think that its not really acceptable then sure, you may delete the room or have a mod delete it, whatever the process is. I don't have the energy to debate/defend myself any further @BillDubuque

Comment: @Goku I'm not familar with the history of your rooms (as briefly mentioned by amWhy). I simply thought some more context might be helpful in understanding how such matters may arise, and how to best deal with them.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, KReiser, BillDubuque  flag offensive posts in the specific chatroom for mod attention.  This runs the risk of non-site mods running interference.  Else, ask to speak to a math moderator privately, if posting in the mods' office is not possible.

Comment: Indeed, I was replying to @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC request above, and suggesting, requesting, that anyone finding out-of-line comments or discussions to "flag offensive posts...."  It was not reporting. only suggesting the more promising avenues of action.

Comment: @BillDubuque I get that. The reason I suggest room deletion altogether is because if, instead of that, people started raising flags, not only will the room get deleted (which I don't actually want but given the general consensus, going against it would be wasting energy that I don't even have), but I may get suspended as well, and that's hardly fair. I recently returned from a week-long suspension, and now a longer suspension for something not directly my fault would be a textbook definition of unfair.

Comment: @Goku If you are interested in discussion religion then why not do so in a chatroom in christianity.SE?

Comment: @BillDubuque With all due respect, I've had this conversation with Xander before and, I really do not wish to repeat myself and debate all over again. As I said, you may request room deletion, I won't argue against it at this point. All I ask is to be left alone please and thank you.

Comment: @Goku But you invited those you blame in terms of your not behaving well as not being directly your fault?  You, in a gallery room, controlled who could participate, and who could not, and you could have changed that permission at any point. But didn't.  So I'd consider that as your direct permission to behave as such.

Comment: In the end, @KReiser, I'm glad you posted your question.  I'd have preferred a bit more context, but this is an issue that site mods need to deal with, particularly because for users flagging in chat, their informative flags are sometimes declined by non-math-mods.  If anything needs examination, it's the trust in SE-wide-nonmath-mods to appropriately handle chat flags in math.se chats.

Comment: @Gokuカカロット- If you wish to be left alone, then you should probably close the room. Any action you take on a stack exchange site is taken in the context of the community. This isn't like a Discord server, where people can set up their own individual communities, and only interact with those they choose. If you post here, or set up a chat room, you should expect responses and many eyes on your actions.

Comment: But I too admit to being mystified as to why you don't open a chat room on Christianity.SE. it seems like a perfect place to have those discussions, and I'm guessing it could come to the attention of even more people who are interested in those subjects.

Comment: I have no idea how to close a room, or I would've done it already for the sake of what little remains of my sanity @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: Heh, you're right, it's not at all obvious how a user can close a room. But there did seem to be an option to bulk move messages, in case you want to go the "move to Christianity.SE" route. I think there's a process that automatically closes chat rooms that are inactive for a certain period. It looks like you could lock down the room for a long period, and then it would happen automatically, maybe?

Comment: Or just get a mod to delete it altogether (like I originally proposed) and be done with all this nonsense once and for all? @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: Oh, sorry, I hadn't realized you had requested for a mod to close it already. Or if you hadn't, then I think the most direct route is for you to request them to. Probably use the "Contact" link at the bottom?

Comment: The sub-issue of my room has been completely resolved. I've asked Xander to delete it, and he has just done so. Now, as I said before, I just ask to be left alone, thank you.

Answer (score 21):

I think that anything that creates community is good for the community.

It strengthens the community to have community activities and discussions, even when they aren't about mathematics. Just like how, in life, we as individuals are all more than just mathematics.

By way of example, suppose we want to have a book club. Why would you want to have a book club here instead of on literature.se? Because you're having it with math.se people. The character of the discussion will be different.

The only exception is when a room consistently generates conflict. Those are bad for the community. We delete those rooms.

Comment: I had wished that deletions could be based on content, but I understand that it can be very difficult to make a good, clean statement about what those content standards would be, and (hopefully) it's a problem that won't arise too often, so that'd be mostly wasted effort. So I thank you for your clarification. And I also want to point out that, as generating conflict is what drives deletion, if people see something objectionable, they might, despite personal preference, have to generate some conflict at that location.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Sure. The key word there is consistency. We don't get rid of rooms based on one argument, only when there is a pattern of discord (in practice, when a ton of flags keep coming in from the same place).

Comment: "Why would you want to have a book club here instead of on literature.se? Because you're having it with math.se people. The character of the discussion will be different." That reasoning is precisely why I had a room of my own here instead of just going into anime.SE, Christian.SE, Gaming.SE or programming.SE to talk about this stuff

Comment: @ペガサスSeiya the folks who were talking the most in that room weren't math.se people, though - your most frequent chat partner in there doesn't even have a math.se account,  and the next most frequent partner after that last logged in to math.se 9 months ago. So even if you accept Alexander Gruber's opinion above, there's still a gap between that and what was happening.

Comment: Any and all people (except for a few) were welcome in there. You're indirectly suggesting that I should've restricted anyone who wasn't from MathSE. Your logic doesn't hold up, nor do you provide an actual solution. That said, this debate is irrelevant now. I had the room deleted by Xander, I do not possess the strength to debate an entire community even if I genuinely believe I did nothing wrong  @KReiser

Comment: @KReiser: Ironically, there is a pattern of discord users bringing their buddies and favourite topics into SE chat.